# CLT and 2 variables

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, central-limit-theorem

Okay so there are 2 variables $D_i$ and $V_i$. Now $D= D_1 + D_2 + ... + D_N$  and $V = V_1 +.. +V_N$
Now I know the relationship is such that $E[D_i - a*V_i] = 0$ and 
$Var[D_i - a*V_i] = E[D_i]$ where $a$ is a constant.

Using the central limit theorem my tutorial solutions say:

$(D-a*E[V])/N$ is Normal $N(0, E[D]/N^2)$

when personally I think it should be
$(D-a*V)/N$ Normal $N(0,E[D]/N^2)$

Can someone pls explain how $D-a*E[V]/N$  is Normal $N(0, E[D]/N^2)$ using those 2 facts i mentioned earlier. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems you are right,  I cannot figure out the variance for $(D-a*E(V))$

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be $Var[D_i] = E[D_i]$?

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure

Comment: Hm, I can prove it using $Var[D_i] = E[D_i]$ --not getting where you want with your assumption.